# Non-GUI FTP server

Tags: windows, ftp, command-line, sftp

I am looking for an open source or free command line FTP server for Windows.
I need it for testing purpose, so I will run it as a user application and not as a service.

Some solutions I found (not yet tested):

- [SlimFTPd](http://www.whitsoftdev.com/slimftpd/) (Despite open source under the BSD license, SlimFTPd download is blocked by Chrome/Firefox as malicious.)
- [IndiFTPD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/indiftpd/)
- [FTPDMIN](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/ftpdmin/)

They look unmantained.
Do you know something more recent?

Answer (score 4):

[Swiss File Knife](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/files/?source=navbar) contains, among other utilities, a simple FTP server:

- free
- cross-platform
- CLI

Short tutorial: [Instant simple FTP server](http://stahlworks.com/dev/index.php?tool=ftpserv).

Comment: Looks like an interesting tool. I'll take a look on it, maybe it'll take place near tools from Russinovich and Nir Sofer.

Comment: +1: I saw in the past   
Swiss File Knife Extended Edition, but I didn't realised there was an open version too.